# Unable to read the input file content that containing % sign

Tags: perl, input

I am having simple open file input as showing below, which I have no problem reading the content from the input file, but not entirely readable.

```
open(IN,"<$modelRoot/Local_$project.pm") || die "ERROR\: $!";

    while(<IN>)
    {
        $temp = $_;
        chomp($temp);
        printf "$temp\n";
    }
```

The content that I printed out looks fine until the point that is a % sign.
This is the original input file content

```
my %LocalToolData = (
```

This is the content that I print out, it gives a warning too

```
Use of uninitialized value in printf at rfinteg_v4.pl line 846, <IN> line 24.
Use of uninitialized value in printf at rfinteg_v4.pl line 847, <IN> line 24.
my 0calToolData = (
```

**Question**: How do I read % sign from the input file and at the same time avoid having the warning?

Comment: As @tadman's answer says, use `print` and not `printf`, unless you actually need to specially format the output. And it's even better to use [say](https://perldoc.pl/functions/say) (`say "hi";` -- no need for newline)

Comment: I get a more useful warning on perl 5.24: `Missing argument in printf`.  If you are on an older version, consider upgrading.

Answer (score 8):

`printf` does formatting using `%`, it's a reserved character. The first argument to `printf` is a *template string*, not any string.

You should be using `print` unless you want to make use of that feature.

You should not use `printf` with any content containing `%` unless you have corresponding placeholder values for that.

It even [says in the documentation](https://perldoc.pl/functions/printf):

> Don't fall into the trap of using a `printf` when a simple `print` would do. The `print` is more efficient and less error prone.